# Extract input transfer function

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

Can someone explain me how to figure out the $U(s)$ equation for the following control system ? i've tried  to follow this procedure:

$Y(s) =\frac { G(s)C(s)+D(s) }{1+ G(s)C(s)+D(s)}$

where $D(s)$ is the laplace transform of $d_y(t)$

then i know that:

$G(s) =\frac { Y(s) }{U(s)}$

so i've extract $U(s)$ and apply the inverse laplace transform in order to get $u(t)$.

I report the function value :

$G(s) = \frac {1}{s+3.6} , C(s)= \frac{6.25}{s} , r(t) = 0, d_y(t) = 2.5\delta(t), d_a(t) = 0$

[image]

Comment: How did you derive your initial expression for $Y(s)$ as a function of $D(s)$? Namely, it looks incorrect.

Comment: I have it from the theory..what  should i use ?